# Is there a way to debug monkeyrunner Python scripts in PyCharm or any other IDE?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

MonkeyRunner is an Android tool to run automation test with Python script. It's built based on Jython, a Java version Python interpreter. My question is, is there a way to debug the python scripts when use MonkeyRunner? I mean step over each line.

Answer (score 0):

After some search. I found this: http://www.jython.org/docs/library/debug.html

Because monkeyrunner is based on Jython. So theoretically this is possible. But this document doesn't how to do in Eclipse or Intellij Idea. But for now, because the demand doesn't exist anymore. Maybe I'll dig deep in the future when I need...